# Switching back to libxl from xend without rebooting

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtual-machines, xen, libvirt

I did something dumb: I enabled `xend` over `libxl` and started an instance with `xend`.

Now, `libxl` won't start any instances, even though I got rid of all the `xend` instances and stopped `xend`:

```
root@xen1 [~]# virsh start xen-pv-yolo
error: Failed to start domain xen-pv-yolo
error: internal error: libxenlight failed to create new domain 'xen-pv-yolo'
```

From the log file `/var/log/libvirt/libxl/xen-pv-yolo.log`:

```
libxl: debug: libxl_create.c:1342:do_domain_create: ao 0x7fea1c0075c0: create: how=(nil) callback=(nil) poller=0x7fea1c001400
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:600:libxl__domain_make: cannot change hotplug execution option once set, please shutdown all guests before changing it
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:743:initiate_domain_create: cannot make domain: -3
libxl: debug: libxl_event.c:1591:libxl__ao_complete: ao 0x7fea1c0075c0: complete, rc=-3
libxl: debug: libxl_create.c:1356:do_domain_create: ao 0x7fea1c0075c0: inprogress: poller=0x7fea1c001400, flags=ic
libxl: debug: libxl_event.c:1563:libxl__ao__destroy: ao 0x7fea1c0075c0: destroy
```

I've got some existing `libxl` instances running, and it would be an inconvenience to power them off in order to reassert `libxl`'s dominance.

**How can I get `libxl` to start instances again after I enabled and disabled `xend`?**

<sup><sub>It is already known that a reboot would resolve this issue, but I would prefer to avoid a reboot.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

Run this command:

```
xenstore-write libxl/disable_udev 1
```

That's it.

## Explanation

This one was difficult to troubleshoot because there is no documentation on how the "hotplug execution option" works behind the scenes.

If you go into the Xen source code to the line number where the error occurs, you would see this:

```
    if (libxl_defbool_val(info->run_hotplug_scripts) != hotplug_setting &&
        (nb_vm - 1)) {
        LOG(ERROR, "cannot change hotplug execution option once set, "
                    "please shutdown all guests before changing it");
        rc = ERROR_FAIL;
        goto out;
    }
```

(Taken from `~/xen-4.4.1/tools/libxl/libxl_create.c`)

I'll spare the C language debugging, but once you trace back all the variables to see where they are loaded, you'll find yourself at `/etc/xen/xl.conf`, where an option `run_hotplug_scripts` can be set.  It defaults to `1`.  **If you set this to 0, virtual machine creation will start working again on the `xl` command (not through `libvirt`).**

Unfortunately, `libvirt` loads `libxl` using a different source for the `run_hotplug_scripts` setting.  To determine this, I attached an `strace` to `libvirtd` and tried to start a virtual machine.

The answer was all in here:

```
[pid  1194] 06:53:39 write(47, "libxl/disable_udev\0", 19) = 19
[pid  1194] 06:53:39 read(47, "\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\7\0\0\0", 16) = 16
[pid  1194] 06:53:39 read(47, "ENOENT\0", 7) = 7
[pid  1194] 06:53:39 rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f80c9a89710}, NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  1194] 06:53:39 write(43, "libxl: error: libxl_create.c:600:libxl__domain_make: cannot change hotplug execution option once set, please shutdown all guests before changing it\n", 148) = 148
```

The last line shows the error about the "hotplug execution option".

The file descriptor `47` was for interactions with the `xenstored` database.

The first line is a request for the `libxl/disable_udev` data object in the database.

*`libxl/disable_udev` for `libvirt` is the equivalent of the opposite of `run_hotplug_scripts` in `libxl`.*

The second line is a read showing that the object doesn't exist.

By default, `libvirt` will assume that the not existing or not being set to `1` (true) means "Yes, do run hotplug scripts."  This is the problem.

To fix the problem, just create the object and set its value to `1`.  This command does that:

```
xenstore-write libxl/disable_udev 1
```

Reading the object to confirm that it was stored in the database:

```
root@xen1 [~]# xenstore-read libxl/disable_udev
1
```

---

#### Before

```
root@xen1 [~]# virsh start xen-pv-yolo
error: Failed to start domain xen-pv-yolo
error: internal error: libxenlight failed to create new domain 'xen-pv-yolo'
```

#### After

```
root@xen1 [~]# virsh start xen-pv-yolo
Domain xen-pv-yolo started
```

---

What's nice about this fix is that you won't have to worry about it going away after a reboot.  As long as `xend` doesn't run into conflict with `libxl` after the reboot, you don't need to run this fix again.